# How do I pass worksheet and ranges as variables?

Tags: vba, excel, range, worksheet

I want to pass the names of sheets and ranges between subroutines. The following throws a "Subscript out of range" error:

```
Sub This()

    x = "Sheet1"
    y = "D3"

    MsgBox (x.Range(y).Value)

End Sub
```

This is [a sample of my Project Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHcLN.png).

[image]

Comment: This is basically a repeat of your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39783461/293078. The answer is that your sheet is called "valuation", not "Sheet1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your worksheet's [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa175750(v=office.11).aspx) is **Valuation**; its Worksheet [.CodeName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx) is **Sheet1**.

```
dim x as string, y as string
dim xx as worksheet, yy as range

x = "Valuation"
set xx = worksheets(x)
y = "D3"
set yy = xx.range(y)
debug.print yy.address(0,0, external:=true)  '<~~returns Valuation!D3 (with the workbook name)

debug.print Sheet1.name    '<~~returns Valuation from CodeName
```

Comment: I only know how to refer to a worksheet by its `Name`, how do you refer to it by its `CodeName` ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent there is example in the link `VBAProject.Sheet1.Range("A1")` or just `Sheet1.Range("A1")`